# running into issues with html and css

Tags: html, css, class, properties, document-body

I have a class named body. I'm adding some CSS to it. I already had a property called background color and I'm trying to add another property, once I added it both properties it wasn't working and I want to know why?

Comment: Please add more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give more details about the problem you are having. Also note that with css property and value declaration should end with a semicolon.

```css
.body {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the properties you adding use proper syntax (semi-colons especially). It's likely you forgot to add a semi colon at the end of your first CSS property.

Also check if you are adding the property to the right class.. giving it a unique name will help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare body as class again unless you add something to it, body is global class and not really need to be re-declare again.

Answer (score 0):

You should have stated your question by adding the code here to know where your error is, but you can note this:

1. make sure in your CSS, your prperty starts with point, i.e the full stop symbol, so it should be `.body`
2. inside your parenthesis, that is the curly brackets, write your property, followed by a colon and the its attribute followed by a semi-colon, the you proceed with another property. 
   sample

HTML
`<div class="body">This is the class named body</div>`

CSS

```
.body {background: blue; color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also check your  style sheet link to HTML, I mean to if you correctly  link  main. Css file to your html Index.